# mouseover and mouseout functions in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html

```
<div class="hidden-nav">
    <h4>lorem</h4>
    <ul class="decor-menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">321</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- hidden-nav -->
<aside class="fixed-col">
<div class="fix-wrap cf">
    <div class="fixed-col-inner">
        <h1>123</h1>
        <div class="menu-button">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="close-menu"></a>
        </div><!-- menu-button -->
        <div class="menu-side">

            <ul class="second-nav">
                <li class="open-hidden-nav"><a href="#" onclick="return false">SHOW HIDDEN MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- menu-side -->
    </div><!-- fixed-col-inner -->
    </div><!-- fix-wrap -->
</aside><!-- fixed-col -->
<aside class="fixed-col-closed">
    <div class="fix-wrap">
        <div class="fixed-col-closed-inner">
            <div class="menu-button">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="open-menu"></a>
            </div><!-- menu-button -->
            <ul class="closed-fav">
                <li class="fav-ico"></li>
                <li><a href="#">0</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="closed-social">
                <li class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="vk"><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- fix-wrap -->
</aside><!-- fixed-col-close -->


<div class="to-top">
    <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
</div>
<section class="main-section cf opened-side">
    <div class="col">
        <article class="item">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/img1.jpg" height="286" width="366" alt=""></a>
            <h2><a href="#">header text</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus possimus ab adipisci sit tenetur assumenda cupiditate iure modi minus repellat corrupti reiciendis sapiente sunt porro autem temporibus impedit quaerat perspiciatis?</p>
            <p>Unde consectetur vitae consequuntur error rerum laborum atque sequi explicabo aut necessitatibus omnis doloremque beatae voluptatum soluta fugiat nulla reiciendis deserunt. Dolore molestiae sint atque labore at quam ducimus itaque?</p>
            <p>Architecto facere eius magnam sed quae odit doloribus dicta. Aperiam consectetur magnam reprehenderit quod sint consequuntur quisquam ab delectus tempore in laudantium quis voluptate iure voluptatem minus placeat nulla officiis.</p>
            <a href="#" class="read-more">22</a>
            <div class="hidden-article-item">
                <p class="author"><a href="#">123</a></p>
                <p class="like-and-view"><span class="view">12</span> <span class="like">5</span></p>
            </div><!-- hidden-article-item -->
        </article>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I need it so that:

- When user hover in `.open-hidden-nav a` - appears dropdown menu, and if hovered `.hidden-nav` it stays visible
- When user changes target (anything else instead `.open-hidden-nav a` and `.hidden-nav`) - dropdown menu hold 1s and disappear.

I wrote this jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".open-hidden-nav a").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(".hidden-nav").addClass('open');
});

$(".hidden-nav").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(".hidden-nav").addClass('open');
    $(".open-hidden-nav").addClass('active');
});

$(".open-hidden-nav a").on("mouseout", function () {
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('.hidden-nav').removeClass('open');
    }, 1000);
});

$(".hidden-nav").on("mouseout", function () {
    setTimeout( function(){
        $(".hidden-nav").removeClass('open');
        $(".open-hidden-nav").removeClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

but it does not work correctly, and css transitions are working in mouseover but are not working on mouseout..

One other question - Is it that mouseover and mouseout functions can be used cross browser or on mobile devices such as iPad?

Here is [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yw6wqq85/2/), I hope you'll help me)

Comment: i think blur event can help to you

Comment: I'm new in js, please,  write more about it if you can.

Comment: This could do with another edit to make it easyer to read, but im not sure how to word it. (the section about what you need the code to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, tuned your code a little and I believe it covers the desired functionality.

**Fiddle**: [Horizontal dropdown menu](http://jsfiddle.net/kshfzk1e/)

**Code:**

$(window).load(function () {
    var closeTimeout;

```
$(".open-hidden-nav a").hover(
//Hoverin;
function () {
    clearTimeout(closeTimeout);
    $(".hidden-nav").addClass('open');
},
//Hoverout;
function () {
    closeTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".hidden-nav").removeClass('open');
        $(".open-hidden-nav").removeClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});

$(".hidden-nav").hover(
//Hoverin;
function () {
    clearTimeout(closeTimeout);
    $(".hidden-nav").addClass('open');
    $(".open-hidden-nav").addClass('active');
},
//Hoverout;
function () {
    closeTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".hidden-nav").removeClass('open');
        $(".open-hidden-nav").removeClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});
```

});

**Explanation:**

Basically I've changed the mouseover and mouseout events with [hover syntax](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), which accepts two functions as parameters. One for *hoverin* and one for *hoverout*, this fixes the problem you have with the inconsistency of mouseout.

The second change is exposing your timeout as a globally accessible variable so you can shut it down if you happen to move your mouse from the hidden menu back to the button that opens it. Because, after all, we don't want it to hide considering your mouse is over what opened it in the first place.

In all other cases it will close within one second.

Comment: Thank you, but I need close that menu when user hover anything else except `.open-hidden-nav` and `.hidden-nav`. In your fiddle I hover some other menu item (eg 7) and menu dont dissapears.

Comment: Yeah, fixed now, check again the link.